# Mail forwarding using Lotus Domino

Tags: email, lotus-domino

We use Domino 8.5.3 environment. We want to "forward" an email  message to another email address. But to do so we will have to first parse a token from the "subject line" of the original incoming email. And then if that token is found, we will have to forward this message to another email address. Can this be easily be done using Domino without some LotusScript programming?. How can this be done by setting Domino messaging rules if at all can be done smoothly. Please provide me some sample links which can be useful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a mail rule using the "Subject contains" option with a "send copy to" action. Here's an example:

[image]

---

This question is more suited for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an agent that is triggered by the event "When mail arrives" and use @Functions, something like

```
@if( @contains( Subject ; "Token" ; @MailSend( .......
```